# Bootstrap input control width is too short

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having an issue with my controls showing far less than 100% using Bootstrap 3.  This is an example:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, all but the Tags control are far shorter than their container.  Tags started showing with full length after making it a Tokenfield.  The code that generates this is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                <b class="panel-title">Information</b>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Information" style="color: black;"><span id="InfoCollapseIcon"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse in" id="Information">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label text-left col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @title = "The unique name of the generator." })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Rinse and Repeat the above -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make my controls fill their container's width?

Comment: If possible create working snippet.

Comment: do you have .form-control class on the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generated a project from a template check for this rule in `Content/Site.css`

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: This was the issue.  I can't believe I didn't see that.